# Alias object in graphql,

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I know if my data is coming like

```
{
id: 123
address: xyz
name: hello

}
```

and I want to alias name during Query I can do it like

```
query {
 identification: id
 address 
 full_name : name

}
```

So my data will look like this:

```
{

  identification: 123
  address: xyz
  full_name: hello

}
```

but I want my upcoming data to look like this:

```
{

  id : 123
  info: {
     address: xyz
     name: hello
   }
  

}
```

How can I achieve this within GraphQl Query only how can I give alias `info`

Comment: you should know that you have to define type ... read docs!!

Comment: Checkout the spec for more details http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Field-Alias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no GraphQL syntax that would allow you to do that client-side. Either apply the transformation programmatically inside your client code, or else change your schema on the server to reflect the data structure you need.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this. GraphQL alias can only change name of a field.